# string dentro de una query

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy creando un package con querys dinámicas al cuál le quiero hacer una select a partir de un parámetro de entrada Tabla.

Dentro del procedure tengo:

```
querysql varchar2(100);

BEGIN

querysql := 'SELECT RPAD(NVL(description,' '),20,'n') FROM '||Tabla||'';
execute immediate querysql;
commit;
end;
```

Si hiciese una select del campo normal. Ejemplo:

```
querysql := 'SELECT description FROM '||Tabla||'';
```

no habría problema pero al decirle que me rellene los espacios vacíos con la letra 'n' no me lo coge porque se hace un lío con los strings.

He probado en declarar la variable espacio y relleno para llamarlo des de la querysql igual que hacemos con tablas pero tampoco funciona. Ejemplo:

```
querysql varchar2(100);
espacio varchar2(1);
relleno varchar2(1);

    BEGIN

    espacio := ' ';
    relleno := 'n';

    querysql := 'SELECT RPAD(NVL(description,' ||espacio|| '),20,'||relleno||') FROM '||Tabla||'';
    execute immediate querysql;
    commit;
    end;
```

Alguna solución?

Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función CHR(), devuelve el caracter asociado al numero que envies según codificación UTF-8.
CHR(34) son las comillas dobles y CHR(39) la comilla simple.

Puedes escribir tu consulta así:

```
querysql := 'SELECT RPAD(NVL(description,' ||CHR(39)||espacio||CHR(39)||'),20,'||CHR(39)||relleno||CHR(39)||') FROM '||CHR(39)||Tabla||CHR(39)||'';
```

Answer (score 0):

Para manejar las comillas, simplemente debes duplicarlas donde sea necesario:

```
querysql := 'SELECT RPAD(NVL(description,'' ''),20,''n'') FROM ' || Tabla;
```

Pero te diré que no le veo el sentido de hacerle un `execute immediate querysql;` sin manejar los resultados de la consulta. Me imagino que se trata solamente de un ejemplo, y que en realidad tienes más código...